# Can you pull more then a play-set (4x) in MTG Duels Origins?

Tags: magic-duels

I have not quite figure it out yet, In Magic the Gathering Duels Origins for any console, can One obtain any card in the booster pulls if you already have a play-set of 4x of that card?

Because of the new deck editor/creator you do not need more then a play-set (4x) to use the same cards in any deck you create.

but when you earn enough coins (150 currently) or spent real money to purchase them for the 6 card booster, you are guaranteed 1 rare / mythic, 1 uncommon and 4 commons, from what I can tell from being about 20 boosters in.
Once a player progresses further enough I would imagine one would be more likely to pull mythic cards the further they got as they would have all the rares. Assuming you cannot pull cards again if you already have a play set...

Answer (score 6):

No, you cannot get more than a playset of any single card. In fact, the maximum you can get of any single card depends on the rarity. You can get a total of

- 4 of any common
- 3 of any uncommon
- 2 of any rare
- 1 of any mythic rare

If you look at your card collection, cards that you already have all available copies of will have their count highlighted in orange.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the game won't give you any more copies of cards you already have the maximum number of. So far I don't own more than 4 copies of any card, so seems plausible.